# what are the features that are extracted from the last pooling layer of inceptionv3?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network, spyder, transfer-learning

what are the features that are extracted from the last pooling layer of inceptionv3? I'm using inceptionv3 to extract features from clothes . I extracted the features from the last pooling layer to use them in another model.

Answer (score 0):

It is composed of 2048 features maps of shape `8x8`. I really depends of your input image they don't look all the same. You can try to see them by yourself. For instance, this image (before resizement to 300x300) :

[image]

will have features looking like (8 of the 2048 features) :

[image]

Here the code used :

```
model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(include_top=False,weights='imagenet',input_shape=(300,300,3))

img=cv2.resize(cv2.imread('test2.jpg'),(300,300))

pred=model.predict(np.array([img])/255)[0]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4, figsize=(15,6))
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flatten()):
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.imshow(pred[:,:,i], cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```